# Dataframe formation structure

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dictionary given below

`d={'key1': ['val11', 'val12', 'val13'],
   'key2': ['val21', 'val22', 'val23']}`

I am struggling to create a dataframe like following

```
key1 value11
     value12
     value13

key2 value21
     value22
     value23
```

I am using pandas and here is my effort

```
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df=df.unstack()
data = pd.DataFrame(df)
data
```

but I am getting the above data frame and I need only **two columns** that have **keys** and **values** the same way as they are right now. I don't need highlighted number column. Any help will be appreciated a lot.

[image: Dataframe Image]

Comment: That is not column it's index ([MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html)). i don't think it's possible to achieve format of dataframe you have mention above.

Comment: You may want to use transpose. try this `df.T` if it helps.

Comment: ```pd.concat(pd.DataFrame(v).assign(key=k) for k,v in d.items()).set_index('key',append=True).swaplevel(1,0)```?

Answer (score 0):

How about `melt`:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).melt()
```

Output (chain above with `set_index` if you want):

```
  variable  value
0     key1  val11
1     key1  val12
2     key1  val13
3     key2  val21
4     key2  val22
5     key2  val23
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question but i don't need repeated `key1` and `key2`. Something like reduce by key.